# Huge difference in validation loss between k-fold and hold-out cross validation approach

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've created a CNN model for image classification task. At the beginning, hyperparameters were tuned to achieve as small training and validation loss as possible. My model was evaluated using hold-out cross validation technique.

The whole dataset consists of around 1,2k images and it was divided such that: 70% was for training, 20% for validation and 10% for testing.

Here are the losses and accuracy scores calculated by the model after 1500 epochs of training:

```
Training set: loss: 0.0617 - accuracy: 0.9803
Validation set: loss: 0.0887 Accuracy: 0.9723
```

And this is the result for k-fold cross validation apporach:

```
Training set: loss: 0.7389 - accuracy: 0.6569 
Validation set: loss: 1.8677 - accuracy: 0.3550
```

In case of k-fold, loss on validation set was increasing with each epoch while training loss was decreasing and there is a huge difference between losses as you can see.

I have TensorFlow's preprocessing layers added to my model at the beginning:

```py
class CNNClasifier(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, num_filters=30, dense_units=20, num_classes=3):
    super().__init__()

    self.preprocessing = Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.3)
    ])
```

My model also uses TensorFlow's datasets instead of numpy array to pass data to the training process.

But in order to put k-fold cross validation to work I had to concatenate train and validation datasets using `numpy` arrays. Maybe preprocessing is not properly done while training the model with `numpy` arrays instead of `TensorFlow's datasets`?

Code for datasets concatenation:

```py
train_images = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: img)))
train_labels = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))
validation_images = np.concatenate(list(validation_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)))
validation_labels = np.concatenate(list(validation_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))

inputs = np.concatenate((train_images, validation_images), axis=0)
targets = np.concatenate((train_labels, validation_labels), axis=0)
```

k-fold cross validation code:

```py
NUM_EPOCHS = 1500
num_of_folds = 5
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=num_of_folds, shuffle=True)

accuracy_scores = []
losses = []

for fold, (train, val) in enumerate(k_fold.split(inputs, targets)):
  print(f"Fold {fold + 1}/{num_of_folds}")

  cnn_model = CNNClasifier()

  cnn_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

  cnn_model.fit(inputs[train],
                targets[train],
                batch_size=80,
                epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                validation_data=(inputs[val], targets[val]))

  loss, accuracy_score = cnn_model.evaluate(inputs[val], targets[val])
  accuracy_scores.append(accuracy_score)
  losses.append(loss)

score = np.mean(accuracy_scores)
mean_loss = np.mean(losses)
```

What can make such a big difference between the losses? It is hard for me to believe that such a huge difference results only from a different split between training and validation set.